# Missing operand on filtering by date

Tags: c#

```
DateTime fromDate = dateTimePicker1.Value, toDate = dateTimePicker2.Value;
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
bs.Filter = "DatePurchased >= '" + fromDate.ToShortDateString() + "' AND DatePurchased '" + toDate.ToShortDateString() + "'";
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

---

I don't know how to solve this, please help anyone my error is

SyntaxErrorException was unhandled

Syntax error: Missing operand after ''1/20/2014'' operator.

Comment: To be honest, this is a pretty clear, straightforward error message; you are missing an operand in your query. Did you check your filter query to see where that opereand might belong?

Comment: sorry still newbie in programing :) still thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the operand in the second part of your filter after the `AND` statement.

Change the filter.

```
"DatePurchased >= '" + fromDate.ToShortDateString() + "' AND DatePurchased '" + toDate.ToShortDateString() + "'"
```

To

```
"DatePurchased >= '" + fromDate.ToShortDateString() + "' AND DatePurchased <= '" + toDate.ToShortDateString() + "'"
```

Note that I added the `<=` operand after the second `DatePurchased` field.

*It was a guess to use `<=` as your previous statement. This may not be the correct operator.*

Answer (score 0):

Where you have

```
"' AND DatePurchased '"
```

you should have

```
"' AND DatePurchased < '"
```

So, it looks like this :

```
bs.Filter = "DatePurchased >= '" + fromDate.ToShortDateString() + "' AND DatePurchased < '" + toDate.ToShortDateString() + "'";
```

The ">=, <" syntax is used assuming that `toDate` = `fromDate + span + 1`. "<" or ">" is always better than ">=" or "<="